# Failed to resolve com.android.billingclient:billing:dp-1

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

```
project(":android") {
apply plugin: "android"
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

configurations { natives }

dependencies {
    compile project(":core")
    compile "com.android.billingclient:billing:dp-1"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.0"
    compile "com.android.billingclient:billing:dp-1"


}
```

}

i have a following gradle code in my android studio project and it still gives me an error "Failed to resolve com.android.billingclient:billing:dp-1", why it won't sync? Should i attach something more?

Comment: You should publish your answer as an answer, not inside the question itself.

Comment: done, as you wish :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

com.android.billingclient:billing:dp-1 is not present in mavenCentral but in jcenter. All you need to do is to add jcenter() to the repositories section.

```
    allprojects {
apply plugin: "eclipse"
apply plugin: "idea"

version = '1.0'
ext {
    appName = "FidgetSpinner"
    gdxVersion = '1.9.6'
    roboVMVersion = '2.3.0'
    box2DLightsVersion = '1.4'
    ashleyVersion = '1.7.0'
    aiVersion = '1.8.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    maven { url "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    jcenter()        <<<<<<------------ ADD THIS LINE TO MAKE IT WORK
}
```

Comment: +1 I almost went too far to update gradle to 3.x as I knew for libgdx project, it's risky and not well support. Good to know it's different problem.