# Failed to resolve com.android.billingclient:billing:1.0

Tags: android, in-app-billing, android-billing, play-billing-library

I have similar issue like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44741850/3926506) but in my case gradle cant't to resolve billing library v1.0 even if I add `jcenter()` repository into build script:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {url "https://maven.fabric.io/public"}
    }
    dependencies {
       classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0"
       classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0"
       classpath "io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.24.4"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found solution [here](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter?filterByPkgName=com.android.billingclient). You need to add http://jcenter.bintray.com to repository list:

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://jcenter.bintray.com" }
}
```

[image: documentation button]

Comment: jcenter has been shut down. any modern fixes for this?